# Encrypt a Python state machine

Tags: python, numpy, encryption, state-machine

I would like to create a finite state machine that my users cannot see, but can import as a module; or possibly as an encrypted text file to be decrypted and eval(); or ??? I'm open to suggestion as I'm really unsure how to proceed.

- It must be able to handle NumPy arrays.
- The remainder of the script must be open source to the user.
- Use of the machine would eventually expire.

The state machine must remain NATURAL INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY; 100% secure hidden.

How would I go about this? Here is a sample of what I'm looking to do:

```
import random
import time
import numpy as np

def state_machine(a,b,c):
    # This machine should be hidden from users
    expiration = 1500000000
    if time.time() < expiration:
        state = 0
        if a[-1]>b[-1]<c[-1]:
            state = 1
        elif a[-1]<b[-1]<c[-1]:
            state = -1
        return state
    else:
        return 'subscription expired'

def generate_3_random():
    # Generate some random data for testing purposes
    a = np.random.random(2)
    b = np.random.random(2)
    c = np.random.random(2)
    return a,b,c

a,b,c = generate_3_random()
print [a,b,c]
state = state_machine(a,b,c)
print state
```

Sample output

```
>>>[array([ 0.320481  ,  0.83016095]), array([ 0.15776184,  0.35658263]), array([ 0.96922252,  0.78727468])]
3
```

Taking a module path, the user version would then look like this:

```
import my_encrypted_machine
import random
import time
import numpy as np

def generate_3_random():

    # Generate some random data for testing purposes
    a = np.random.random(2)
    b = np.random.random(2)
    c = np.random.random(2)
    return a,b,c

a,b,c = generate_3_random()

print [a,b,c]

state = my_encrypted_machine.state_machine(a,b,c)

print state
```

Output would then be in the same format as the non protected version above.

Comment: If the user can run the code, they can also read the code.  All you can do is make it slightly harder.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/4639/8715

Comment: There are various Python code obfuscators, but if it is really important to you, don't use Python. Use a compiled language and keep the source closed.

Comment: Intellectual property protections are not dependent on whether you can obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could do a few things:

**Completely hide the inner workings of the state machine**

If you really don't want them to be able to see the code, put it on a server, and give them a remote API (REST or so) to access it over the network. (and secure the server!) Then unless they hack into your box, they won't be able to see your code.

**Temporarily prevent your users from figuring out how it works / prevent casual hackers from seeing your code**

Obfuscate the code. See [How do I protect Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code) or [how to encrypt python source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578452/how-to-encrypt-python-source-code) for thoughts on this topic. TLDR; it's not easy. Use something else than python :)

What you're describing with an encrypted textfile would require you to provide the user with a decryption key, which probably means they can decrypt themselves.

Comment: thanks to all that contributed this morning with quick responses.  "how to encrypt python source code?" was an excellent read which demonstrated the impossibility of my request.  I will be taking the client/server api approach.